# How to configure deployment from Eclipse to Wildfly

Tags: eclipse, maven, deployment, wildfly

When I deploy app using *jboss-as-maven-plugin*

```
mvn clean jboss-as:deploy
```

application works. When I try to deploy from Eclipse using e.g. "Full publish", it doesn't.

I've compared versions of application being deployed and seems that "Full publish" simply copied what has been specified in *Properties > Deployment Assembly*.

Is it possible to use this plugin during "Full publish" ? 
I want to make use of hot deploy feature for jsp, but without properly configured automatic deployment from Eclipse I'm rather blocked.

regards

Lukas

```
Wildfly 8.0.0.CR1 
Eclipse Keppler SR1 
org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.2.Final
```

Comment: This might be helpful: [how-to-deploy-war-of-maven-project-to-jboss-server-from-eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842560/how-to-deploy-war-of-maven-project-to-jboss-server-from-eclipse) even though it seems a bit old

Answer (score 0):

I just updated to wildfly, and I had to use this to deploy to jboss.

https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/deploy-mojo.html

Answer (score 0):

I am as troubled as you are with this.

After searching a bit more I have found these two suggestions in SO:
A: [Eclipse Kepler and JBoss Wildfly hot deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20213032/eclipse-kepler-and-jboss-wildfly-hot-deployment?rq=1) and
B: [Hot deploy on JBoss - how do I make JBoss “see” the change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969279/hot-deploy-on-jboss-how-do-i-make-jboss-see-the-change)

In both cases I did a `mvn install` in order to create `war` file and then deployed it by right clicking the server and using add-remove. Now every time I changed something and then pressed save the console output would change informing me that `20:02:45,086 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS018565: Replaced deployment "web.war" with deployment "web.war"`. If I pointed my browser to the URL of my project the changes would indeed be there.

NOTE: Be careful when undeploying in the second case. I had it undeployed from eclipse but when going at: `http://localhost:9990/console/App.html#deployments` I could still see the war so I also had to remove it by pressing the remove button from the Management Console.

I hope this helps but I am not sure that this kind of functionality is hot deployement though.