# "Full Publish" does not work for publishing Dynamic Web Project on wildfly since using Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss, wildfly

Since i am using maven in my JSF Project it seems that eclipse does not support "Full publish" Button correctly anymore. I was adding maven support with right-click on Project > Configure > Convert to Maven Project...

After importing required dependencies and updating Project from pom.xml Server runs correctly but publishing changes (Java Code) takes no effect. Just cleaning whole Project and Server takes effect.

```
Eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
Wildfly Full Profile 10.1.0.Final
JBoss Tools 4.4.4.Final 
with Embedded Maven installation (3.3.9) and m2e-wtp
```

I tried solutions like:
[How to configure deployment from Eclipse to Wildfly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285996/how-to-configure-deployment-from-eclipse-to-wildfly) or [Hot deploy on JBoss - how do I make JBoss "see" the change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969279/hot-deploy-on-jboss-how-do-i-make-jboss-see-the-change?noredirect=1&lq=1) but none of these changes have helped.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Test</groupId>
  <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
      <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>23.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>3.10</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Is there a mistake e.g. in my pom.xml or any solution to restore Pulish  function?

Comment: Why have you changed the directory structure?

Comment: You mean because of the <sourceDirectory> part in pom? (Sorry, i am a newbie to Maven). I have not (consciously) changed the directory structure and the pom was generated automatically by "Convert to Maven Project..."

Comment: Don't do that follow the default folder layout https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply but changing the project structure did not work. I have not figured out what the problem is but after installing new eclipse oxigen and jboss tools everything works fine and eclipse triggered publish correctly.