# JavaEE Servlet won't hot deploying

Tags: eclipse, servlets, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I started working with javaEE and currently doing some basic servlet stuff. So I'm using Eclipse neon and GlassFish server. Created a dynamic web project and everything works fine.

The problem are servlet file changes. If there is a change in the java file nothing happens - no hot deploying/ republish. I have to complete remove the application from server and re add it to see the changes.

- Changing .html files works (doesn't effect servlets changes)
- Rebuild does nothing
- Server "clean" does nothing
- Server restart does nothing
- "Automatically publish when resources change" is of course on, hence the html changes

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be, that it does not observe the correct files for triggering the redeployment.

I haven't tried it for GlassFish, but could see the same behavior for WildFly as you described with the default server settings.

Try to add `\.class$` to section Application Reload Behavior in server settings. (This will be the case for exploded deployment.)

*Credits to varantes answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20213032/eclipse-kepler-and-jboss-wildfly-hot-deployment) question*